# Where do I place the defuse library, to avoid the Call to undefined method?

Tags: php, static-libraries

I am keen to try the defuse library for two-way crypto. I have copied the defuse directory and subdirectories to my web root directory, and the .phar file to /var/www/lib/defuse-crypto.phar as instructed by InstallAndVerify.md. In my test script I have included

```
require_once('/var/www/lib/defuse-crypto.phar');
```

However I get the following error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: 
Call to undefined method Defuse\Crypto\Crypto::CreateNewRandomKey() in /var/www/encryptTest.php:12 
Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/encryptTest.php on line 12
```

I have used one of the example scripts

```
$key = \Defuse\Crypto\Crypto::CreateNewRandomKey();
$message = 'We are all living in a yellow submarine';
$ciphertext = \Defuse\Crypto\Crypto::Encrypt($message, $key);
$plaintext = \Defuse\Crypto\Crypto::Decrypt($ciphertext, $key);
echo "cipher is $ciphertext<br/> plaintext is $plaintext";
```

I have also tried using

```
$key = Crypto::CreateNewRandomKey();
```

etc, without the fuller path, and I have tried

```
use Defuse\Crypto\Crypto;
```

I get the same error message. It seems to be a simple issue of directory paths, but the .phar stuff is beyond me! I would be really grateful if someone could push me in the right direction.  I am not using composer, and I don't really want to. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more trials I found the answer, there were three errors, here is the working code.  Amongst other things the documentation tutorial (tutorial.md) omitted the require_once( /...phar) line in the tutorial examples, which misled me.  The script can be placed in the web root directory or any sub-directory, the namespaced classes will still be called correctly. So here it is.

```
<?php 
use Defuse\Crypto\Key;
use Defuse\Crypto\Crypto;
require_once "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/defuse/defuse-crypto.phar";

$key = Key::CreateNewRandomKey();
$message = 'StackOverflow is great';
$ciphertext = Crypto::Encrypt($message, $key);
$plaintext = Crypto::Decrypt($ciphertext, $key);
echo "cipher is $ciphertext<br/> plaintext is $plaintext";
?>
```

You will need to add

```
use Defuse\Crypto\KeyProtectedByPassword;
```

if you want to use a stored and password-protected key, and

```
use Defuse\Crypto\File;
```

if you want to encrypt files. The authors suggest placing the .phar file in /var/www/lib, but I have placed it in /var/www/defuse along with the source files which are in /var/www/defuse/src. It doesn't affect the way the namespaces are called, as long as the .phar file is correctly referenced in the require_once() statement.